# In App Billing - product not found

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I need help with my Android in-app-purchase. I set up the library IInAppBillingService.aidl. Then I did everything I saw in some good looking tutorials and before I did this I read the Google documentation several times. Im from Germany, so my English is not quiet perfect - but I think I get the important things.

The manifest is setup and everything looks fine. This morning I used Googles "test-purchase-item" and the code seems to be right. I could "buy" this test product - no error.

Now I tried to purchase my own product (not only from my own device, at my girlfriends Google-Account I get the same failure => "The item you were attempting to purchase could not be found."

Hmmm... I'm not able to figure out whats wrong. I already asked many people in a German programmers community, but nobody could help me. :-/

Edit: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461097/in-app-billing-item-not-found-error?rq=1) at Stack-Overflow, but I'm quite sure my error isn't produced by these source of errors.

Edit2: **When I use Googles test-purchase-item, logcat tells me that I couldn't buy this stuff twice**. Am I right, when I suppose that my code (library, etc) is correct, but something went wrong with my product?

I appreciate every posting which brings some light in the dark hole of "in-app-billings" :D
Best wishes
Martin

Comment: Are the product names in the code same as in the developer console's product's page ?

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply.
static final String ITEM_SKU = "de.clevercomputing.justdrive.donation"; 

This is what I add to my "DonationActivity"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have the same error.  While I have not found the cause of my error, I will provide a concise list of solutions to try that have resolved this error for others.

The app should be signed and uploaded to the developer console.  If it is not uploaded to "Production", several more of the following could apply

The in-app item has to have the status "Active".

Enter an account other than the developer account in "testing access" portion of the Developer Console -> Settings.

Use a device with the primary account in the "testing access" that is not the developer account.

Double check the spelling of your SKU/id.

The uploaded apk and the apk used for testing have to be the same version and identically signed.  This is generally not true if you are running the app through Eclipse.  The simplest one shot solution is to side install the exact same apk file you uploaded onto the test device.

Double check the license key.

EDIT: "Publish" the app.  This includes screenshots, description, etc.  It can still be in Alpha/Beta testing.

Wait 3 hours for app, SKU and testing accounts to be propagated.

The following is a link to my question that includes many links related to this question.
[“The item you were attempting to purchase could not be found” Android in-app billing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23918190/the-item-you-were-attempting-to-purchase-could-not-be-found-android-in-app-bil)

Comment: Hey, I solved the problem by myself - the mistake I made was that I did not wait long enough. :)

But thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @MartinPfeffer how long did you wait?, may i know i am getting same error. i Found everything perfect but still getting same error

Comment: Hello M.J., I waited about 3 hours. But a other problem could be made by testing the purchase with your own Google Account (Developer-Account)... At my own device (my own Google Account) the error isn't gone. At other devices with other Google-Account-IDs everything works fine. ;)